# How to chain nullish coalescing in if statement to determine not undefined or null

Tags: javascript

My goal is to check if any variables are `undefined` or `null` while not checking for falsy values (ie an empty string is okay, zero is okay).

I have it written like this:

```
  if (
    !line?.weight ??   // If weight is defined then...
    !line?.id ??       // If id is defined
    !line?.type ??     // If type is defined
    !line?.coordinates ?? // If coordinates are defined
    false              // don't run!
  ) { // one of these variables is undefined or null
   }
```

I used to have it written as `typeof line?.weight !== 'number' || typeof....`

I'm just asking this questions to see if there is a better way to do this or if the `?? false` is needed. Or if this actually works or I'm missing something and it's going to bite me.

I guess the more I look at it, can I even negate a non undefined or null value to provide an undefined or null value which would work in this case? I think this won't work.

Comment: Do you want to check if all of them are non-nullish or if any of them are non-nullish?

Comment: I think the way you are understanding nullish coalescing is different, if the condition before `??` is true then it'll use the right side value i.e., if `line?.weight` is `undefined` then it'll take `false` but then your condition looks like `!line?.weight ??` is `undefined` when there's `weight` with some value other than `null` or `undefined`. 
Long story short, simply you need to remove `!` for the conditions

Comment: @NithishGandesiri I'm not sure about that. Because if the first is not null it'll stop right there.... which isn't want I want. I want it to check all the values and make sure they are all not null and not undefined. And apologies my previous comment was wrong.

Comment: @adiga I meant to say I want to make sure all of them are non-nullish.

Comment: This is the shortest I can think of: `if ( line?.weight != null && line?.id != null && line?.type != null )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple check for `null` to those values. like `line?.weight == null`.

1. Use `==` so it will check for `null` and `undefined`.
2. Apply `||` between conditions for multiple `properties`
3. Wrap condition into `(...)` and use `not` `!` condition.

Final condition will be like below.

```
if (!(line?.weight == null || line?.id == null || line?.type == null || line?.coordinates == null)) { ... }
```

You can check your output below.

```js
function test(line) {
  if (!(line?.weight == null || line?.id == null || line?.type == null || line?.coordinates == null))
    console.log("true");
  else
    console.log("false");
}

let line = { weight: 123 };
test(line); // false

line = {weight: "", id: "", type: "", coordinates: ""};
test(line); // true

line = {weight: "", id: "", type: "", coordinates: undefined};
test(line); // false

line = {weight: "", id: "", type: null, coordinates: 0};
test(line); // false

line = {weight: 0, id: 0, type: 0, coordinates: 0};
test(line); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest possible solution I can think of. But looks like the kind of requirement you are looking for might not be achieved using `nullish coalescing`. Hope this helps for your requirement.

```js
const checkIfNullOrUndefined = (obj, keys) => {
  let bool = false;
  (keys || []).forEach(key => {
    if(typeof obj[key] === "undefined" || obj[key] === null) {
      bool = true;
    } 
  });
  
  return bool;
}

let line = {weight: 123}
console.log(checkIfNullOrUndefined(line, ["weight"]))
console.log(checkIfNullOrUndefined(line, ["weight", "id", "type", "coordinates"]))

line = {weight: "", id: "", type: "", coordinates: ""}
console.log(checkIfNullOrUndefined(line, ["weight", "id", "type", "coordinates"]))

line = {weight: "", id: "", type: "", coordinates: undefined}
console.log(checkIfNullOrUndefined(line, ["weight", "id", "type", "coordinates"]))

line = {weight: "", id: "", type: null, coordinates: 0}
console.log(checkIfNullOrUndefined(line, ["weight", "id", "type", "coordinates"]))

line = {weight: 0, id: 0, type: 0, coordinates: 0}
console.log(checkIfNullOrUndefined(line, ["weight", "id", "type", "coordinates"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something I came up with (may be a dirty trick though). Here `val` is a js variable which can be of any type.

```
if(typeof val !== typeof(val ?? 1)) {
    //implement your logic here 
}
```

**Explaination** : If val is not `null or undefined` then nullish coalescing will always return the val, therefore it's similar to comparing `typeof val == typeof val` which always returns true. Otherwise it always returns false as `typeof (undefined|null) != typeof(1)`

Answer (score 0):

`left ?? right`
If **left** is **not** null, use it.
If it is null, use **right**.
(1)

`!(value)`
Is value true or false? (Or truthy/falsy for non-boolean types?)
If true, return false.
If false, return true.
(2)

*... now your code...*
`!(value) ??`
**The left-most operand is evaluated first...** (3)
`!(value)`
Is value true or false?
If true/truthy (eg not **null**, **undefined** 0, ""), **return false**.
If false/falsy (eg **null**, 0, "", **undefined** etc..), **return true**.

*...so now you have...*
`TRUE/FALSE ??`
If **left** is **not** null, use it.
If it is null, use **right**.

Booleans are not "null".
Your code is evaluating your left operand as **not null**.

Even if your "value" is null, you're not returning the value...
You're returning the *truthiness* or the *falsiness* of the value.

You asked `if the ?? false is needed`
The `??` operator requires two operands so something is always needed after the final `??`, yes.

You mentioned  `I want it to check all the values and make sure they are all not null and not undefined.`

The `??` will only continue to the next expression (ie check all of them) if it receives a **nullish** input. Like a magic key, it **NEEDS to see** a **nullish**, before moving onto the next operand.
The moment it sees anything that is **not** nullish, it will short circuit and return that value. It can not see a **!nullish** and continue to the next expression.

Unfortunately, along with the Optional Chaining operator, it is the only operator that evaluates for "nullish"-ness. All other operators evaluate for truthiness or type etc but not exclusively "nullish"-ness. Therefore even when trying to *cast* or *conditionally cast* like in your example, all values will be cast based on whether they fall into a certain type or truthiness. There is no combination therefore that will allow for you to glean the "non-nullishness" of more than one value per operation, because no other operators distinguish it (nullish-ness) as exclusively separate from other data types, and once you use any other operator, they will evaluate and potentially even cast, based on their own inputs and returns, and position on the operator precedence table.

There are proposals to include this ability into JS (eg introducing an inverse null coalescing operator,) but so far, none exist. (For now..) **Manually testing the data types of your values may be your cleanest option.**

(1) [info on what 'nullish coalescing' operator returns here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20for,first%20expression%2C%20too)  [AND HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing#:%7E:text=The%20nullish%20coalescing%20(%3F%3F)%20operator%20is%20a%20logical%20operator%20that%20returns%20its%20right%2Dhand%20side%20operand%20when%20its%20left%2Dhand%20side%20operand%20is%20null%20or%20undefined%2C%20and%20otherwise%20returns%20its%20left%2Dhand%20side%20operand.)
(2) [info on what 'Logical NOT' operator returns here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#:%7E:text=Returns%20false%20if%20its%20single%20operand%20that%20can%20be%20converted%20to%20true%3B%20otherwise%2C%20returns%20true)  [AND HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#:%7E:text=The%20logical%20NOT%20(!)%20(logical%20complement%2C%20negation)%20operator%20takes%20truth%20to%20falsity%20and%20vice%20versa.%20It%20is%20typically%20used%20with%20boolean%20(logical)%20values.%20When%20used%20with%20non%2DBoolean%20values%2C%20it%20returns%20false%20if%20its%20single%20operand%20can%20be%20converted%20to%20true%3B%20otherwise%2C%20returns%20true)
(3) [more info about operator precedence here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_precedence#:%7E:text=happen%20at%20all.-,Table,-The%20following%20table)
(4) [info on the different types here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#:%7E:text=implicit%20type%20conversions.-,Primitive%20values,-All%20types%20except)